# Duplicate answer was deleted - how can I get it undeleted after deleting the other answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Contact Form 7 fields list by form id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088554/contact-form-7-fields-list-by-form-id/61886792#61886792)

I got an answer deleted by a moderator for posting it to several questions.
I now removed the answer on the other question, but how can I undelete this one? It's a very important answer.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the meta site.

I have undeleted the other answer since you deleted the other one. We don't mind leaving either of them. The moderator who deleted picked one at random, or maybe the latest one. Since neither of them had upvotes, it was difficult to choose anyway.

Next time you have an issue like this, raise a custom flag to moderators. I know that [you need at least 15 rep to be able to flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), so I guess a meta post was a good call in that particular case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I got the answer after 4 days of hard work, so I was answered on both of the Question, that's Why duplicate happened. thank you again. best regards